# Find specific,closest point between two others

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

I have array/dict (whatever) with x,y of points:

```
1000 - 460
2000 - 470
3000 - 520
4000 - 520
5000 - 620
6000 - 660
7000 - 730
8000 - 700
9000 - 650
10000 - 600
11000 - 510
12000 - 430
13000 - 380
14000 - 330
15000 - 280
```

on chart they looks like this:
[image]

Could you help me with finding another point, to be more specific, find Y of point when for example X = 8136?
Is there any way to estimate this to know the x, y of points between which it is located?

Comment: The `array/dict (whatever)`, would be easier to reproduce if you defined it as such

Comment: What have you tried so far? this seems like a trivial interpolation question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a "technique" called interpolation; it is an estimation based on your data set. There are different kinds of interpolations, where linear interpolation is the simplest one but produces the biggest error; to make it in python you could use scipy.interpolate() from the scipy library or dataframe.interpolate() from pandas library, please refer to the links below for more information:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-interpolate/